# Assistance required for designing a Customized Android View

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm designing a simple Multimeter look-alike android app.  Idea is to have a rotary control knob like control which will enable me to select the parameter i want to measure. i.e Voltage, Current or Resistance.

Although i'm quite clear about the functionalities (w.r.t Multimeter inner workings), i'm falling short of ideas for the UI.

With [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) i was able to create a stylish Multimeter look alike image and a rotary select knob. My idea is to use the **multimeter** image as the **background** and the **rotary knob** placed on top of the multimeter image. Also, i should be able to rotate the image of the knob using Matrix class available in **android.graphics.Matrix**

The question is how do i design such a thing in Android ?

Should i have to use Compound Views in Android or

Should i have to create some custom views and include this in the main layout file. ?

Or Is there a better solution which i could make use of ?

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Cheers
VATSA

Comment: for my project i used this http://hub.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer--mobile-8868 There is just a flag (that you have to delete for your Multimeter), which would make your knob continue spinning when you remove your finger from the image while spinning it

Comment: Thanks i saw this link when i googled. But again how do i Superimpose the rotating knob/dial on another image. In my case i have two images. 1. Static background image 2. Rotating dial on the static image. I just need the layout design strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is from my recent project:

View (`controller_activity.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/controller_image" android:src="@drawable/your_knob_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity (ControllerActivity.java) (Logic [and rest] from http://hub.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer--mobile-8868):

```
public class ControllerActivity extends Activity {

    //your fields

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.controller_activity);

        ImageView controllerImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.controller_image);

        //the rest from link
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing the same. But how do i add the other image ? in this case ?

Comment: @this-Me what do you mean the other image? The other `Drawable`? You insert it into the `drawable` folder in your project structure and refer to it in `ImageView` by writing `android:src="@drawable/your_knob_image"`

Comment: I actually need to use two images. 1. Static image (Background)      2. Dial/knob Image which i can rotate.

Comment: @this-Me add both to `drawable` folder of your project. 1. Static - in `RelativeLayout` add property `android:background="@drawable/your_background_image"` and to the Dialg/knob image as I have specified in my earlier comment